# Mac kernel panic, how to solve this?

Tags: macos, mac, kernel

I got the following kernel dump my Mac Mini after hibernation. This issue has been a certain event after Mac going into hibernation for a period of time.

Then I tried to reinstall Yosemite on my Mac (not a clean installation, just overwrite the OS itself). However, the problem still exists.

Does anyone understand the log and have any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800329eae4): "Hibernate restore error e00002bf"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp:3330
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8144e2bb30 : 0xffffff8002d2bda1
0xffffff8144e2bbb0 : 0xffffff800329eae4
0xffffff8144e2bc90 : 0xffffff8002e23ce7
0xffffff8144e2bce0 : 0xffffff7f844f8e1d
0xffffff8144e2bd20 : 0xffffff7f844fc64b
0xffffff8144e2bd40 : 0xffffff80032f1f8b
0xffffff8144e2bd90 : 0xffffff800331adfc
0xffffff8144e2bdf0 : 0xffffff80032c58a7
0xffffff8144e2be60 : 0xffffff80032bc4ba
0xffffff8144e2bef0 : 0xffffff80032cacc8
0xffffff8144e2bf40 : 0xffffff80032d3bad
0xffffff8144e2bf80 : 0xffffff80032d3da8
0xffffff8144e2bfb0 : 0xffffff8002e125b7
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(3.1)[97299A71-6EDD-3AD9-AE1D-2F7B61E8AA72]@0xffffff7f844ee000->0xffffff7f8454cfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f83e63000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f83524000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002b00000
System model name: Macmini6,1 (Mac-031AEE4D24BFF0B1)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 9036498843952
last loaded kext at 715956309403: com.astrill.astrill.kext      1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8456e000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 8629758808484: com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver      4.3.4f4 (addr 0xffffff7f8446b000, size 73728)
loaded kexts:
com.astrill.macproxy.kext       2.0.8
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.24
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.24
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB     4.3.24
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv     4.3.24
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch       4240
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs     3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC      1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager        4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient        3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim        1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl       1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver       272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics       10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA       272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog       1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV        1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP     2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport     4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360       930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC       1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri     10.0.6
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController      327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless     1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache     36
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter     404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage      2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC      1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC       2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons       3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET      1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC      1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient     218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall       161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface       97.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib     272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily       4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController     272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily     272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily      3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin      1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC       3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily        2.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub       705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite      705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily        4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily     4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily        4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily     720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime        2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily     2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox      300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch       1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity       1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages     396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore       28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform      3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily     2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm      1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto        1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: Macmini6,1, BootROM MM61.0106.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 10 GB, SMC 2.7f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A544631473634485A2D314736443120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: PLEXTOR PX-128M6S, 128.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: F-104
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of that log, you have three non-apple kexts that could be causing the crash:

- VirtualBox
- Astrill VPN Client
- LittleSnitch

Try uninstalling those apps and see if the crashes stop.  If they do, then you'll have to do some trial-and-error to figure out which one is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mavericks and after upgrading to Yosemite too. With Mavericks I reinstalled OS (including clean installation) and reset [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) as well. Nothing helped.

However I remembered when this started - it was after replacing my Samsung SSD with Plextor one (PLEXTOR PX-256M6S, 256,06 GB). And from your logs I see, that you are using the same model of Plextor (6S).

What's more - lastly I received replacement of my old Samsung SSD, so I replaced the disc once more. After this my MBP wakeups from hibernation without any problems. So in my case for sure it was fault of Plextor PX-256M6S (which otherwise works perfectly fine).

My logs:

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802d29eae4): "Hibernate restore error e00002bf"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp:3330
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8216523b30 : 0xffffff802cd2bda1 
0xffffff8216523bb0 : 0xffffff802d29eae4 
0xffffff8216523c90 : 0xffffff802ce23ce7 
0xffffff8216523ce0 : 0xffffff7faf54be1d 
0xffffff8216523d20 : 0xffffff7faf54f64b 
0xffffff8216523d40 : 0xffffff802d2f1f8b 
0xffffff8216523d90 : 0xffffff802d31adfc 
0xffffff8216523df0 : 0xffffff802d2c58a7 
0xffffff8216523e60 : 0xffffff802d2bc4ba 
0xffffff8216523ef0 : 0xffffff802d2cacc8 
0xffffff8216523f40 : 0xffffff802d2d3bad 
0xffffff8216523f80 : 0xffffff802d2d3da8 
0xffffff8216523fb0 : 0xffffff802ce125b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(3.1)[97299A71-6EDD-3AD9-AE1D-2F7B61E8AA72]@0xffffff7faf541000->0xffffff7faf59ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7fad7a9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7fad524000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x000000002ca00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802cc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802cb00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 35119177800
last loaded kext at 8933270687: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7faec59000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.22
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough   1.0.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5358384758334D314131363030433130
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5358384758334D314131363030433130
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: PLEXTOR PX-256M6S, 256,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```